# How to load webUserControl from external project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webusercontrol

I want to create a modular web application which can load dynamic modules (which have userControls type and inherit from some interfaces) into my page from external class library project, but I load userControls via this code:

```
Control ctl = this.LoadControl("~/MyExternalClassLibraryProject/MyTestModule.ascx");
```

I'm facing this error: `Could not load type 'MyExternalClassLibraryProject.MyTestModule'`

Can anybody help me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it and it works correctly!
please go to [this post](https://forums.asp.net/t/2064690.aspx?Problem%20to%20Page%20LoadControl%20via%20type%20and%20parameters%20) which I created in asp.net forum.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a user control from outside the asp.net application. Consider adding the user control in the project that needs to use it. Or if it doesn't have any UI controls (you only need to use the code behind) then use a web service.

Comment: Hi, i know this can be done (like sharepoint, dotnetnuke, ...) which can accept external assemblies as module.

Comment: Right, that option too, then check this might be helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479318.aspx

Comment: Thanks Lamar, but it's Precompiled scenario and i don't want to this. I'm looking for a standard way like sharepoint or dotnetnuke to do this action!

Comment: I don't think you can do it without using a dll if it was from a different solution. Anyway if you found a way please share your results.